# Move work to another branch Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, hgsubversion

I am currently using Mercurial for sub-version control in my project. Now I am suppose to work on a new branch 2.7 but I confuse to work with branch 2.6, I have developed the new feature which the feature on 2.7 but I build on 2.6. And now I want to move this feature to branch 2.7 properly but I don't know how can I move it properly. Is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using `hg graft`, which copies changes from one branch to another and unlike `hg rebase` is not destructive (relevant if you're doing this for the first time and may be making mistakes or if you need the feature to be present on both branches).

To copy changes to a branch `dest-branch`, do the following. First update to the branch you want to copy the changes to:

```
hg update dest-branch
```

Then, use graft to copy the revisions you want from the original branch, e.g.:

```
hg graft -r start..end
```

where `start` is the first revision you want to graft from the source branch and `end` is the last revision.

You may encounter conflicts if they can't be merged cleanly, which you have to resolve them (as you'd do in a merge), then use `hg graft --continue` to graft the remaining revisions.

Answer (score -1):

The magic word is RTFM - `hg help rebase`

Comment: I try this but it does not work, It doesn't know this command. Is there any other solution? Thank,